# Create structured list from string line

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have some string, for example:

How can I print this string in form of table:

Should I be using the `split` method?

Comment: you could use regex or explode the string and print the array 3 elements at a time.

Comment: Are you doing this in PHP or Javascript?

Comment: 2 Magic 9000, 3 simon 2035, 4 simon 2035, 5 simon 2035.....

Answer (score 0):

It's rough but it will do it's job:

```
var zm = "2 Magic 9000 3 simon 2035 4 simon 2035 5 simon 2035 6 simon 2035 7 simon 2035 8 simon 2035 9 trolled 666 10 s555s 555 11 s555is 555"

var tokens = zm.split(' ');
for( var i=0; i < tokens.length; i+= 3){
  console.log(tokens[i] + ' ' +tokens[i+1] + ' ' +tokens[i+2]);
}
```

Of course the premise is that the input has always that format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's probably a prettier solution involving Regex, but this brute-force solution does the job.

```
Things = 'string'.split(' ')

for (var i = 0; i < (Things.length/3); i++) {
    console.log(Things[3*i]+' '+Things[3*i+1]+' '+Things[3*i+2])
};
```

It should work as long as the string is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = zm.match(/\S+\s\S+\s\S+/g);
console.log(lines.join('\n'));
```